# Is there a graphical (GUI) front end for hdparm?

Tags: hard-drive, spindown

Is there a graphical (GUI) front end for `hdparm` to configure spin down for my hard drives in Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: It seems not: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/3195

Comment: thanks aking1012 and Marco! seems I have no luck then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No, at this time there is not.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130519032831/http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/3195)